# Lua-protobuf: "lua_protobuf" does not exists

Tags: python, lua, protocol-buffers

I run this code command from the command prompt:

```
C:\Python34>python.exe c:/Users/Jefecito/Downloads/lua-protobuf-master/lua-proto
buf-master/setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing top-level names to lua_protobuf.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing requirements to lua_protobuf.egg-info\requires.txt
writing lua_protobuf.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to lua_protobuf.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

error: package directory 'lua_protobuf' does not exist
```

And it seems to start. I look in the folder to verify that everything is there and I can see:
setup.py
lua_protobuf (folder) with two .py files

I downloaded it directly from this page and I'm just trying to get it to work:
https://github.com/indygreg/lua-protobuf

I'm not experienced in Python whatsoever so it might be an easy error or something but I don't think it's a typo (but I don't rule anything out). If I type the path wrong it returns "Errno 2 No such file or directory".

Anyone able to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run that command from the  `lua-protobuf-master` directory (use `cd` to get there).

Comment: Thanks! An easy mistake as I expected!